# How to get coordinates of a mxCell?

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht, jgraphx, jgraph

I need to get the coordinates (x,y) of a mxCell that i find by his Id, but when i call getGeometry() on it, it gives me null and after i get NullPointerException.

```
private double getX(String node){
    mxCell cell = (mxCell) ((mxGraphModel)map.getGraph().getModel()).getCell(node);
    mxGeometry geo = cell.getGeometry();//this line give me the null value
    double x = geo.getX();//NullPointerException
    return x;
}
```

map is the mxGraphComponent that contains all the graph.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `String node` argument should be mapped to the cell's `id`.

Basically, you select all cells, get them and iterate over them. Since nearly everything in JGraph is `Object`, you need some casts.

```
private double getXForCell(String id) {
    double res = -1;
    graph.clearSelection();
    graph.selectAll();
    Object[] cells = graph.getSelectionCells();
    for (Object object : cells) {
        mxCell cell = (mxCell) object;
        if (id.equals(cell.getId())) {
            res = cell.getGeometry().getX();
        }
    }
    graph.clearSelection();
    return res;
}
```

You might as well check if `cell.isVertex()` before calling `getGeometry()`, since its implemented differently on edges.

Edit: Followed your approach and the following works for me, too. Seems like you need the extra cast `(mxCell)`.

```
mxGraphModel graphModel = (mxGraphModel) graph.getModel();
return ((mxCell) graphModel.getCell(id)).getGeometry().getX();
```

Comment: I also found the `void graph.selectVertices()` method, which might be useful, if one wants to query vertices only.

Comment: It causes some problem because it must be done by the EDT because the selection is also graphical